# What's the role of quantum mechanics in the radiotherapy for tumor and why the proton radiotherapy is much more expensive than photon radiotherapy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, radiation, medical-physics

I am wondering the role [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) plays in the process of [radiotherapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_therapy), such as by photon, or by proton. In particular, I am curious about why the [proton radiotherapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_therapy) is much more expensive than photon radiotherapy. What's the physics behind radiotherapy?

Comment: You're really asking two separate questions here:  what is the role of QM in radiotherapy, and why is proton radiotherapy more expensive than photon radiotherapy.  In my opinion, the second question is the more interesting one, and you might want to edit the title of your question to feature that question instead of the first one.  (I'm pretty sure the answer to the first question is "very little".)

Comment: Ok,I will edit it.

Answer (score 3):

Radio therapy is based on quantum mechanics, because it has to do with particle interactions with biological targets, which are composed by atoms and molecules. All these interactions belong to the quantum mechanical regime.

[Radiation therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_therapy)

> Radiation therapy or radiotherapy, often abbreviated RT, RTx, or XRT, is therapy using ionizing radiation, generally as part of cancer treatment to control or kill malignant cells and normally delivered by a linear accelerator. Radiation therapy may be curative in a number of types of cancer if they are localized to one area of the body. It may also be used as part of adjuvant therapy, to prevent tumor recurrence after surgery to remove a primary malignant tumor (for example, early stages of breast cancer). Radiation therapy is synergistic with chemotherapy, and has been used before, during, and after chemotherapy in susceptible cancers. The subspecialty of oncology concerned with radiotherapy is called radiation oncology.

You ask:

> I just want to know why the proton radiotherapy is much more expensive than photon radiotherapy. What's the physics behind radiotherapy?

As you see by the excerpt above, accelerators are necessary to give photons or protons high enough energy.

Protons are more penetrating than photons and because they need higher energy accelerators they are more expensive.

The physics is for *delivering* by *scattering*  enough *energy* on the cells of malignant tumors to destroy them and contain the malignancy, with a good *focus* so as not to destroy healthy tissue.